# How to check whether index before creating in elastic search

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Code is below

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
#es.indices.delete(index='my-index', ignore=400)
es.indices.create(index='my-index', ignore=400)
for e in test:
    es.index(index="my-index", body=e, id=e['id'])
```

I need to check whether `index exists` first before creating index. If exists then my incoming logs has to append if there is no index I need to create it first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not creating your index with specific mappings or settings, you can ditch that step and simply index your data and the index will be created automatically.

So this is sufficient:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
for e in test:
    es.index(index="my-index", body=e, id=e['id'])
```

Comment: lets say there is no my-index at beginning? do it create new my-index?

Comment: is there any thing like if es.indices.exists("my-index") == False:

Comment: Again, you don't need to as the call `es.index` will create the `my-index` index automatically